# Why do we need Fuseki Server?

Tags: sparql, jena, semantic-web, fuseki, tdb

I am developing an application, which is using triple store (Jena [TDB](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/tdb/)). It is clealy mentioned that TDB [Supports](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/tdb/java_api.html) SPARQL update and Query. Also, I understood that [Fuseki](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/fuseki2/index.html) is SPARQL server, that supports Update and Query as well. I do not find answer do the following questions:

1. If TDB supports SPARQL query and update, then why we need Fuseki?
2. Can I store my data in TDB and then access it in my application without using Fuseki?

Any response from your side will be valuable.

Comment: 1) Fuseki is an application to make your TDB endpoint accessible via web. 2) You can use TDB as a local store without Fuseki. Fuseki just makes it accessible for remote queries.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To expand on the comments you already received

TDB is an in-memory database backed by persistent disk storage which runs within a JVM and is accessible only within that JVM.  TDB stores can only be accessed by a single JVM at a time (and TDB will enforce this restriction) so you cannot use TDB on its own if you need to share data between multiple JVMs

Fuseki is a web server that implements the [SPARQL Protocol](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-protocol/) which is a standard way to expose a RDF database for querying/updating via HTTP.  TDB is the database used by default underneath Fuseki though Fuseki can be configured on top of other RDF databases if desired.

Since Fuseki runs in a single JVM it can be used to share access to a TDB database with multiple applications because those applications access Fuseki via HTTP and Fuseki handles all access to the TDB database within its JVM.  Additionally since the SPARQL Protocol is a standard you can use Fuseki to allow non-JVM applications to access your TDB database since they simply interact with Fuseki via the protocol and don't need to know how to interact with TDB directly.

To summarise:

- If you only ever need to have one application access a TDB database then you can use TDB directly
- If you need to have multiple applications (or non-JVM) applications access a TDB database then use Fuseki over TDB